# what's an efficient way to document your RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, documentation

I'm working with a large set of test cases and am wondering what an efficient way of documenting them all is. Right now I'm just using a spreadsheet to crudely record them, so I'm curious if there's a better way.

Looking for something like [Apipie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails) or [zipmark](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation), which can automatically generate documentation for an API

Comment: What do you want your documentation to expose?

Comment: zipmark "Automatically generates API documentation from RSpec".  It seems like that's what you're looking for, so it is unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: I haven't actually used it, but it seems like zipmark uses RSpec tests to document an API, rather than creating a higher level documentation of the tests themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/square/fdoc

> In a Rails or Sinatra app, fdoc can help document an API as well as
>   verify that requests and responses adhere to their appropriate
>   schemata.

It can help generate API documentation:

> fdoc also has a scaffolding mode, where it attemps to infer the schema
>   of a request based on sample responses.

https://github.com/square/fdoc/blob/master/docs/scaffold.md